# order dataframe by timestamp while keeping same id as consecutive row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of eventlog and ordered by the time of which each event is saved.
The logs/row correspond to tasks and have an ID and I would like to move the event/row from the same first ID (first event/timestamp for that id) under the first occurance of an ID.

I tried a simple pd.sort_value() by both columns but I can't get the desired result

the final result would look like

```
ID    time
X     01/01/2010
X     03/01/2010
X     04/01/2010
J     02/01/2010
J     03/01/2010
Y     03/01/2010
Y     07/01/2010
Y     08/01/2010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new columns used for parsing:

```
#if need first value per log change 'min' to 'first'
df = (df.assign(new = df.groupby('ID')['time'].transform('min'))
        .sort_values(['new', 'ID', 'time'])
        .drop('new', 1))
print (df)

  ID       time
0  X 2010-01-01
1  X 2010-03-01
2  X 2010-04-01
3  J 2010-02-01
4  J 2010-03-01
5  Y 2010-03-01
6  Y 2010-07-01
7  Y 2010-08-01
```

Another idea by [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) created by aggregate of `min`, so if use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) it sorting correctly:

```
#if need first value change 'min' to 'first'
cats = df.groupby('ID')['time'].min().sort_values()

df['ID'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['ID'], categories=cats.index, ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'time'])
print (df)
  ID       time
0  X 2010-01-01
1  X 2010-03-01
2  X 2010-04-01
3  J 2010-02-01
4  J 2010-03-01
5  Y 2010-03-01
6  Y 2010-07-01
7  Y 2010-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumes `time` to be timestamps.

```py
df = df.join(df.groupby('ID')
               .time.min()
               .rename('time_min'), on='ID')
df.sort_values(['time_min', 'ID', 'time']).drop('time_min', axis=1)


  ID       time
0  X 2010-01-01
1  X 2010-03-01
2  X 2010-04-01
3  J 2010-02-01
4  J 2010-03-01
5  Y 2010-03-01
6  Y 2010-07-01
7  Y 2010-08-01
```